# CSV writer implementation refactored

Tags: c#, csv

Based on my initial implementation found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69829/csv-writer-implementation) and the suggested improvements in answers and comments, I've refactored the code.

The main changes are:

1. Removed redundant buffering.
2. Simplified constructors by implementing a `CsvWriterSettings` class.
3. Refactored `CsvWriter<T>.WriteLine(T value)` to make it more readable with the use of a private nested class `CsvFieldWriter`.

The code as it stands now is the following:

```
public sealed class CsvWriter<T> : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable
{
    private const char EscapeCharacter = '\\';
    private const char EscapedSeparatorCharacter = 's';

    private bool isDisposed;
    private Stream output;

    private readonly Encoding encoding;
    private readonly bool escapeListSeparatorInsideField;
    private readonly bool escapeNewLineCharactersInsideField;
    private readonly List<char> ignoredCharacters;
    private readonly char listSeparatorCharacter;
    private readonly IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> projections;
    private readonly CsvFieldWriter fieldWriter;
    private readonly StringBuilder buffer;
    private object syncObject;

    public CsvWriter(Stream output, IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> projections, CsvWriterSettings settings = null)
    {
        if (output == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("output");

        if (projections == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("projections");

        if (!output.CanWrite)
            throw new ArgumentException("Can not write to specified stream.", "output");

        var csvSettings = settings ?? new CsvWriterSettings(Encoding.Default);
        this.output = output;
        this.projections = projections;
        this.listSeparatorCharacter = csvSettings.ListSeparatorCharacter;
        this.encoding = csvSettings.OutputEncoding;
        this.ignoredCharacters = (List<char>)csvSettings.IgnoredCharacters;
        this.escapeListSeparatorInsideField = csvSettings.EscapeListSeparatorInsideField;
        this.escapeNewLineCharactersInsideField = csvSettings.EscapeNewLineCharactersInsideField;
        this.fieldWriter = new CsvFieldWriter(this);
        this.buffer = new StringBuilder();
        this.syncObject = new object();
    }

    public bool EscapeListSeparatorInsideField { get { return this.escapeListSeparatorInsideField; } }

    public bool EscapeNewLineCharactersInsideField { get { return this.escapeNewLineCharactersInsideField; } }

    public IEnumerable<char> IgnoredCharacters { get { return this.ignoredCharacters; } }

    public char ListSeparatorCharacter { get { return this.listSeparatorCharacter; } }

    public void WriteLine(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        Debug.Assert(this.projections != null);
        Debug.Assert(this.fieldWriter != null);
        Debug.Assert(this.encoding != null);
        Debug.Assert(this.buffer != null);
        Debug.Assert(this.output != null);

        lock (syncObject)
        {
            if (this.isDisposed)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().Name);

            foreach (var projection in this.projections)
            {
                if (projection != null)
                {
                    buffer.Append(this.fieldWriter.WriteField(projection(value) ?? string.Empty));
                    buffer.Append(this.ListSeparatorCharacter);
                }
            }

            this.buffer.Length--;
            this.buffer.AppendLine();
            this.output.Write(this.encoding.GetBytes(this.buffer.ToString()), 0, this.buffer.Length);
            this.buffer.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void WriteLines(IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        if (values == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("values");

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            WriteLine(value);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.isDisposed)
            return;

        lock (syncObject)
        {
            if (this.isDisposed)
                return;

            Debug.Assert(this.buffer.Length == 0);
            this.output = null;
            this.isDisposed = true;
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }

    private class CsvFieldWriter
    {
        private readonly CsvWriter<T> csvWriter;
        private readonly StringBuilder fieldBuffer;
        private readonly bool escapeCharacters;

        public CsvFieldWriter(CsvWriter<T> csvWriter)
        {
            this.csvWriter = csvWriter;
            this.fieldBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            this.escapeCharacters = csvWriter.escapeNewLineCharactersInsideField || csvWriter.escapeListSeparatorInsideField;
        }

        public string WriteField(string field)
        {
            Debug.Assert(csvWriter != null);
            Debug.Assert(field != null);
            Debug.Assert(fieldBuffer != null);

            fieldBuffer.Clear();

            if (this.escapeCharacters || csvWriter.ignoredCharacters.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var c in field)
                {
                    if (c == CsvWriter<T>.EscapeCharacter && this.escapeCharacters)
                    {
                        fieldBuffer.Append(CsvWriter<T>.EscapeCharacter);
                        fieldBuffer.Append(c);
                    }
                    else if ( c == csvWriter.listSeparatorCharacter && csvWriter.escapeListSeparatorInsideField)
                    {
                        fieldBuffer.Append(CsvWriter<T>.EscapeCharacter);
                        fieldBuffer.Append(CsvWriter<T>.EscapedSeparatorCharacter);
                    }
                    else if (csvWriter.ignoredCharacters.Contains(c))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (c == '\n' && csvWriter.escapeNewLineCharactersInsideField)
                    {
                        fieldBuffer.Append(CsvWriter<T>.EscapeCharacter);
                        fieldBuffer.Append('n');
                    }
                    else if (c == '\r' && csvWriter.escapeNewLineCharactersInsideField)
                    {
                        fieldBuffer.Append(CsvWriter<T>.EscapeCharacter);
                        fieldBuffer.Append('r');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fieldBuffer.Append(c);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fieldBuffer.Append(field);
            }

            return this.fieldBuffer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The `CsvWriterSettings` class:

```
public class CsvWriterSettings
{
    private readonly Encoding outputEncoding;
    private readonly bool escapeListSeparatorInsideField;
    private readonly bool escapeNewLineCharactersInsideField;
    private readonly List<char> ignoredCharacters;
    private readonly char listSeperatorCharacter;

    public CsvWriterSettings(Encoding encoding = null, bool escapeNewLineCharactersInsideFields = true, bool escapeListSeparatorInsideFields = true,
                    IEnumerable<char> ignoredCharacters = null)
        : this(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator[0], encoding, escapeNewLineCharactersInsideFields, escapeListSeparatorInsideFields, ignoredCharacters)
    {
    }

    public CsvWriterSettings(char listSeparator, Encoding encoding = null, bool escapeNewLineCharactersInsideFields = true, bool escapeListSeparatorInsideFields = true,
        IEnumerable<char> ignoredCharacters = null)
    {
        this.listSeperatorCharacter = listSeparator;
        this.outputEncoding = encoding ?? Encoding.Default;
        this.escapeListSeparatorInsideField = escapeListSeparatorInsideFields;
        this.escapeNewLineCharactersInsideField = escapeNewLineCharactersInsideFields;
        this.ignoredCharacters = new List<char>();

        if (ignoredCharacters != null)
        {
            foreach (char c in ignoredCharacters)
            {
                this.ignoredCharacters.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool EscapeNewLineCharactersInsideField { get { return this.escapeNewLineCharactersInsideField; } }
    public bool EscapeListSeparatorInsideField { get { return this.escapeListSeparatorInsideField; } }
    public Encoding OutputEncoding { get { return this.outputEncoding; } }
    public char ListSeparatorCharacter { get { return this.listSeperatorCharacter; } }
    public IEnumerable<char> IgnoredCharacters { get { return this.ignoredCharacters; } }
}
```

In order to take advantage of the compiler's type inference I've also implemented the following static class:

```
public static class CsvWriter
{
    public static IList<Func<T, string>> CreateEmptyProjectionList<T>(T value)
    {
        return new List<Func<T, string>>();
    }

    public static CsvWriter<T> CreateWriter<T>(T value, Stream output, IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> projections, CsvWriterSettings settings = null, int bufferLength = 512)
    {
        return new CsvWriter<T>(output, projections, settings);
    }
}
```

And now, an example of how this class could be used would be:

```
var inDebt = from c in customers
             where c.Credit < 0
             select new { c.LastName, c.FirstName, c.Credit };

var projections = CsvWriter.CreateEmptyProjectionList(inDebt.FirstOrDefault());
projections.Add(c => c.LastName);
projections.Add(c => c.FirstName);
projections.Add(c => c.Credit.ToString("C"));

using (var writer = CsvWriter.CreateWriter(inDebt.FirstOrDefault(), stream, projections))
{
    writer.WriteLines(inDebt);
}
```

Is this an acceptable approach or am I off to a bad start with this implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply have a `CsvWriterSettings` field in the `CsvWriter` class, so I wouldn't need to do all of this:

```
this.listSeparatorCharacter = csvSettings.ListSeparatorCharacter;
this.encoding = csvSettings.OutputEncoding;
this.ignoredCharacters = (List<char>)csvSettings.IgnoredCharacters;
this.escapeListSeparatorInsideField = csvSettings.EscapeListSeparatorInsideField;
this.escapeNewLineCharactersInsideField = csvSettings.EscapeNewLineCharactersInsideField;
```

Also, the point of the `CsvWriterSettings` class is to avoid a constructor with numerous parameters. Just have public properties and assign those, e.g.

```
var settings = new CsvWriterSettings
{
  EscapeNewLineCharactersInsideField = true,
  EscapeListSeparatorInsideField= false,
}
```

That is far clearer code that doesn't require someone to figure out which parameter of the constructor corresponds to which property.

I also wouldn't use an `IEnumerable<char>` for `IgnoredCharacters`, I'd go for `ICollection<char>` or even `IList<char>` or `List<char>`.

Comment: The point of doing it this way is because `CsvWriterSettings` is *immutable*. I don't want anyone changing settings once the writer has been initialized; what you are proposing would allow changes to the writer's behavior between calls to `WriteLine(T value)` or `WriteLines(IEnumerable<T> values)` which could create inconsistant csv files. Still I agree that the code is unecesarily verbose. I should just store the `CsvWriterSettings` object in a readonly field.

Comment: All I'm proposing is that you have a `private readonly CsvWriterSettings` which you assign via the contructor; I don't see how that one can be changed between calls.

Comment: I understand, the question is: I create a `CsvWriter` with a specific `CsvWriterSettings`. Then after a while, I *mutate* `CsvWriterSettings`. What happens to the initialized writer? Should it mutate its behavior? Should it ignore the changes? Both options are not *obviously* right, so I want to avoid this alltogether by making `CsvWriterSettings` immutable. You are right concernig the fields initialization, I just need one `CsvWriterSettings` field. The code stands as it does because initially `CsvWriterSettings` was mutable and I had decided to ignore mutations once the writer was created.